# What's this plant?

Tags: identification

I thought this plant was beautyberry but when put next to each other I realized they were differnt. Can you tell me if this is Japanese beautyberry or some other wild plant in FL? 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks to be [Pokeweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana)

As it matures, the stems & berries will take on a purple / redish color. (That plant also looks like it could use some water).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pokeweed is toxic, although the leaves can be eaten if cooked correctly (this involves three separate boiling operations - not something I'd like to try). The root is extremely toxic and can kill a human; eat enough uncooked or poorly cooked leaves and you may also die. It's a relatively pretty plant, but birds will eat the berries and seed it throughout your yard and neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is wilting because I pulled out of a small milkweed garden  that I didn't want this plant in. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is wilting because I pulled out of a small milkweed garden  that I didn't want this plant in. Thanks for the help!